# AngularJS for e-commerce project - is world ready or not yet?

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, seo, analytics

I am preparing e-commerce project in AngularJS, but i have doubts.

1. SEO? Is it problem or not? If i know it is possible to have good SEO
   with AngularJS with google,but what with others searcher engine?
2. I experienced many tools like tools for tracking users (how users
   fill forms, what they do on sites etc.) doesn't work with dynamic
   contents.

Is world ready for dynamic webpages like AngularJS or not yet? I am really not sure... do whole project in AngularJS or static pages...

Maybe some example of working e-commerce project, for example shop or something like that which SEO and users tracking are important? Good ready project is always good prove.

**I just want be sure i wouldn't lose traffic from SEO and i would track and analyze users behavior on my sites. I am not really sure would i?**

Answer (score 1):

Ok , so what I can tell you from my experience with angular :

- SEO is definitely a problem, but there is solutions out there (like https://prerender.io/ ). Is it enough for e-commerce ? I don't know.
- We use google analytics in our (quite big) Angularjs project, it works (it's not as easy to install though, but some have contribute project that can help https://github.com/revolunet/angular-google-analytics )

[EDIT]
For Angularjs e-commerce exemple app you can look at the builtwith page :
https://builtwith.angularjs.org/
And use e-commerce tag.

One of the e-commerce site was : 
https://www.hatch.co/

Comment: What with other trackers? Like hotjar.com? And others integrations with i don't know... affiliate?

And what with https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started about SEO? Is it enough and is it the best solution?

Comment: For hotjar the best way to know is to ask google, then hotjar directly. I don't know if it's the best solution, because I don't know your constraint. What i can say it's that it has been try http://www.sofa.io/

Comment: Mayby do you know one good example of success with AngularJS for e-commerce?

Comment: angular ecommerce site paytm.com